# Is it possible to concatenate an img src in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, concatenation

This might be a silly question but I'm trying to concatenate the source of an image in React to be rendered on the screen, but it's not working.

```
<img src=`https://www.cryptocompare.com/{this.state.cryImage}` />
```

In this.state.cryImage, I only get the second half of the link (I'm pulling data from an API) so for example it would be something like:

`media/19633/btc.png`

Am I concatenating incorrectly or is this just not possible?

Comment: Flagged as This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You've missed $ sign and brackets for attribute

```
<img src={`https://www.cryptocompare.com/${this.state.cryImage}`} />
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you-- Can't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to add `{}` in `src` prop:

```
<img src={`https://www.cryptocompare.com/${this.state.cryImage}`} />
```

Comment: You missed the closing bracket

Comment: Dupe of other answer ;)