# HTML img source from different items

Tags: html

I know the  question sounds weird but i dont know how to better describe it.

I´ve got an HTML Table that should show an image, which isn´t a problem, but the image source should be an string (for example: /home/pi/img/) combined with an extracted value in curly braces (for example: {/something} -- that equals image.png).

(/something actually shows the image if it contains the complete path)

```
<table class="mytable">
<tr>
<td width="80%"><img src="/home/pi/img/" {/something} height=100 width=100></img></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Is there a way to combine that?

Comment: Which backend you are using , which is returning {/something}

Comment: I´m using IOBroker if it´s known to you

Comment: In react i use it like this <img src=`/home/pi/img/${something}` > and also delete </img> the src is enclosed in `

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48377234/is-it-possible-to-concatenate-an-img-src-in-react

Comment: Thanks got it working! How can i mark that Answer?

Comment: I added the answer so that you can mark for future reference :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In react i use it like this

```
<img src=`/home/pi/img/${something}`>
```

and also delete < /img> the src should enclosed in `